# Docker and RabbitMQ, how to startup service again after removing it

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I am trying to create a rabbitmq cluster using docker, based on the details provided in these two links below, I have it starting up, but not sure how to start up an image/container after I have removed it again.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2kGd2VRJWE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FzqjtU2x6YA

The second video he goes through stopping a node with this command (Excuse the name, not sure yet how to make it more succinct)

```
docker rm -f rabbitcluster_rabbit_node_3_1
```

So my question is, how do I start up the 3rd one that i just remove above? at the moment I have tried this command which is the images name but get is starting separately it would seem.

```
docker run -d rabbitcluster_rabbit_node_3
```

[image]

Can I use anything from the docker-compose.yml or am I going to have to use docker run, as it seems disconnected from the docker-compose.yml file now!?

This is the **docker-compose.yml** that I have written

```
version: "3.9"

services:
    rabbit_node_1:
        build: .
        hostname: rabbit-1
        environment:
            - RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE = "ABCDYJLFQNTHDRZEPLOZ"
            - RABBIT_NODENAME = rabbit1
            - RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE = /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
            - RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS = -rabbit log [{console,[{level,debug}]}]
        ports: 
            - 8081:15672
            - 5672:5672
            - 4369:4369
            
    rabbit_node_2:
        build: .
        hostname: rabbit-2
        # Don't start any of these until rabbit1 is up
        depends_on: 
            - rabbit1
        environment:
            - RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE = "ABCDYJLFQNTHDRZEPLOZ"
            - RABBIT_NODENAME = rabbit2
            - RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE = /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
            - RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS = -rabbit log [{console,[{level,debug}]}]
        ports: 
            - 8082:15672
            
    rabbit_node_3:
        build: .
        hostname: rabbit-3
        # Don't start any of these until rabbit1 is up
        depends_on: 
            - rabbit1
        environment:
            - RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE = "ABCDYJLFQNTHDRZEPLOZ"
            - RABBIT_NODENAME = rabbit3
            - RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE = /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
            - RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS = -rabbit log [{console,[{level,debug}]}]
        ports: 
            - 8083:15672


# docker network create rabbitmq-cluster
networks:
    default:
        name: rabbitmq-cluster
```

This is the **Dockerfile**

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.9-management

COPY rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
COPY definitions.json /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
COPY .erlang.cookie /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie

RUN chmod 700 /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
```

This is the **rabbitmq.conf**

```
loopback_users.guest = false
listeners.tcp.default = 5672
management.listener.port = 15672
management.listener.ssl = false
management.load_definitions = /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
cluster_name = cluster1
cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend = rabbit_peer_discovery_classic_config
cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.1 = rabbit@rabbit-1
cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.2 = rabbit@rabbit-2
cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.3 = rabbit@rabbit-3
```

finally this is the rabbitmq **definitions.json** file

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "andrew", 
            "password": "test",
            "tags": "administrator"
        }
    ], 
    "vhosts": [
        {
            "name": "/"
        }
    ], 
    "permissions": [
        {
            "user": "andrew", 
            "vhost": "/",
            "configure": ".*", 
            "write": ".*",
            "read": ".*"
        }
    ],
    "parameters": [],
    "policies": [], 
    "exchanges": [
        {
            "name": "test.exchange",
            "vhost": "/", 
            "type": "direct", 
            "durable": true, 
            "auto_delete": false, 
            "internal": false, 
            "arguments": {}
        }
    ],
    "queues": [
        {
            "name": "test.queue",
            "vhost": "/", 
            "durable": true, 
            "auto_delete": false, 
            "arguments": {}
        }
    ], 
    "bindings": [
        {
            "source": "test.exchange", 
            "vhost": "/",
            "destination": "test.queue",
            "destination_type": "queue",
            "routing_key": "",
            "arguments": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `docker rm -f` (forcibly) removes a **container**. You cannot start it anymore after that, because it no longer exists.

If you want to create a new container from the service `rabbit_node_3` in your `docker-compose` file, you need to use the `docker-compose` command from within the directory where your `docker-compose.yml` resides:

`docker-compose up -d rabbit_node_3`

Where:

- `up` tells docker-compose to create containers from the named service (`rabbit_node_3`)
- `-d` tells docker-compose that you do not want to attach your terminal to `stdout` and `stderr` of the container started with this command. It would just go in the background and free your terminal for other tasks

Comment: Brilliant thank you, easy when you know how :) much appreciated. You answer also made me aware that the depends_on in the docker-compose.yml was pointing to the wrong name